# Half Bridge waveforms don't look as they should

Tags: power-supply

I made a lot of experiments with the HB stage and I am getting these strange waveforms . The voltage is measured across R_L (scope is isolated from mains, scope GND connected to cap divider mid point @ +190V) (measuring between 0V and HB mid point shows (ignoring offset) the same waveform). It looks like after turning off (in each cycle) the opposite transistor turns on for 1.5 µs and then turns off. This happens both with gate transformer driver and with isolated IC driver. I used different transistor types (normal and SiC MOSFETs, IGBTs, even NPN), all of them produce that strange waveform. Normally I would expect a staircase waveform (first transistor on -> 0V, then turn off -> +190V, then second transistor on -> +380V an so on).
I tried to add a 10µ 1kV pulse cap in series with R_L, waveform still looks the same.

Control signals are coming from SG3525 and they look clean. With the 500µs deadtime. Frequency is 50 kHz. I measured signals on gates and they look as they should (going from -5V to +20V with IC driver and from 0V to +18V with gate transformer).

Attached are schematics of drivers and the oscillograms with augmenting duty cycle. The load are two paralleled wire wound 100W 100R resistors.

What do you think? How can I get the normal, desired waveform?

[image: Waveforms]

[image: HB_ISOL_DRIVER_EVAL_reduced]

[image: power_brd_HB_stage]

Comment: Why are you driving your 50R load into a capacitive divider?  
How much inductance do the pair of paralleled 100R wire wound resistors have?  
What resonance frequency overtones do you get with your pair of wire wound 100R resistors in parallel being driven into a capacitive divider at 50kHz?

Comment: And, the SG3525 has a programmable dead time (that you mentioned) and, are you using that to drive the driving UCC21520?  Note that your schematic appears to also have a dead time RC on the UCC21520.  Which could be creating some crazy wave forms - two dead times.

Comment: _"With the 500µs deadtime"_ - you mean 500ns, right? What are the duty cycles for trace 1-3?

Comment: Show oscilloscope traces that include the control signal. You have a spare input on your scope and, to answer this the scope needs to show input control signal and output signal. Why are your Recom dc-to-dc converters fed from 15 volts when they are 12 volt devices?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 500 ns dead time________
Sorry, mistake. The actual converter are R15... and I forgot to change it in schematic________The inductance of paralleled resistors is 50 µH________Dead time of UCC doesn't play any role. I experimented with 0 ns DT setting, 300 and 1000 ns. I also used other chips Si8275 and 2S8265A with the identical result________"Why are you driving your 50R load into a capacitive divider?" Because it is a HB topology and I used resistive load to test the power stage before connecting it to a power transformer.

Comment: GT Electronics, you are right, thank you! I used paralleled small metal oxide resistors and now the waveform looks as it should. Indeed, there is kind of resonance in the circuit. Could you please explain more: Which components  cause it, how to avoid it and how to calculate it? The phase shift FB will actually defeat this resonance problem, right?